# How to get IP addresses of other Wifi enabled devices by programmatically on the same network?

Tags: android, ip, ip-address, android-wifi

In my Android mobile, I clicked from the phone and saw settings-> Wireless Controls->Wifi Settings and tapped on the network I have connected to. It popped up a Dialog with network status, level, speed, signal strength, IP address and security type. So just I got an IP address of network.

How can I get IP addresses of other wifi enabled devices by giving (known IP address got from my mobile) as a Input?

Actually to be clear, how to give specific known IP address as a Input and must be able to get other Unknown Ip addresses of Wifi enabled devices connected on the same network programmatically in Android 2.3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For getting the IP Address you can check [`getIpAddress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getIpAddress%28%29) in [`WifiInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html)

Pseudo Code,

```
 WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) 
                                     getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 WifiInfo mWifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
 Log.e("IP in Mask Integer", mWifiInfo.getIpAddress()+"");
 Log.e("IP Address", intToIP(mWifiInfo.getIpAddress())+"");

public String intToIP(int i) {
       return (( i & 0xFF)+ "."+((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF)+
                          "."+((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF)+"."+((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF));
}
```

Comment: I have tried a lot, it has shown me only local host. I do not need local host. I need private Ip address.

Comment: I updated the code and checked it give the IP Address of connected Wifi.

Comment: Hi Lalit, it shows only device ip. can we get the internet ip address.. like mobile connected via wifi,2g,3g sim using intenet.(whatever mobile having internet, need that internet ip address)..if possible pls help me..

Comment: How can this be selected as the correct answer when it doesn't answer it!, The question is asking about "other wifi enabled devices" not the device own wifi address.

Comment: Needs `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />` to work.

Answer (score 0):

To find other devices in the same network you need to **SCAN** that network.

Scanning means to find the possible IPs in your subnet (using your IP address and subnet mask you can find the possible range and usually for home routers it is between x.x.x.1 ~ x.x.x.254) then iterate through these IPs and for each IP do PING or try to connect with TCP/UDP to some/all ports until you get a response which means there is an active device using that IP. However, it you get no response at all then it might be that there is no device using that IP or the device is filtering these requests (a firewall dropping your packages) or simply that device doesn't have any listening services.

To learn more about this check out some well known tools like nmap

Answer (score 0):

```
 WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

       WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
       int myIp = myWifiInfo.getIpAddress();

textWifiManager.setText(myWifiManager.toString());
       textWifiInfo.setText(myWifiInfo.toString());

       int intMyIp3 = myIp/0x1000000;
       int intMyIp3mod = myIp%0x1000000;

       int intMyIp2 = intMyIp3mod/0x10000;
       int intMyIp2mod = intMyIp3mod%0x10000;

       int intMyIp1 = intMyIp2mod/0x100;
       int intMyIp0 = intMyIp2mod%0x100;

       textVIewIp.setText(String.valueOf(intMyIp0)
         + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp1)
         + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp2)
         + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp3)
         );
```

Also have to modify AndroidManifest.xml to grant permission of android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

Answer (score -4):

click settings, > wireless & networks > then wlan > click the options button on your phone (it should be beside your home button thingy) then click advanced :)

Comment: The key word is "programmatically". The question wasn't how to find the IP address through the GUI, but how to script it. Stack Overflow is about programming, it's not a general computer help forum.

Comment: I have mentioned that I needed "programmatically"!